# Storyboards and Swift 2.2 Mac App custom segue replace view controller

Tags: xcode, swift, osx-elcapitan, xcode-storyboard, swift2

I am very new to Swift and although have some programming knowledge and have watched a Udemy and Lynda stuff on Swift code I'm struggling a little to move from the playground to an Xcode Project.

I would also like to create a Mac app which makes finding tutorials a little harder.

I want to use latest Swift and Storyboards too, I want to visual lay it out and WWDC suggests storyboards are the best practice for new Mac apps, Lister is a good example.

I can happily create a button and using a segue move between views but I don't want a pop up, modal or sheet, but to in fact replace the view (aka stay in the same window) so I assume this is a custom seque or programmatic only connection which is where I get stuck there is not many simple tutorals that cover this for Mac apps, they all move to iOS when discussing Storyboards. If anyone can help that would be great I have created my Second ViewController and I believe this is the Code to support it , I have connected this to my Second ViewController in attributes

```
import Cocoa

class CreateEditView: NSViewController {

    required init?(coder: (NSCoder!)) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
    }

}
```

Again the examples seem to be different but may not be swift 2.2 (if anyone can also explain what this code is actually doing that would also be great)

Answer (score 1):

I've done a custom segue of this type in Objective-C but it's not easy...and getting constraints right is worse.  Until Apple figures out that view controllers don't necessarily need their own windows, I suggest using a container view.

For this example, I set up `ViewController` with a container view and link a `FirstContained` view controller to it in the storyboard.  It has a "Next" button.

```
@IBAction func goToNext(sender: NSButton) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(ViewController.SecondController, object: nil)
}
```

I create a `SecondContained` view controller in the storyboard and give it the identifier "second_contained".  It has a "Back" button.

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: NSButton) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(ViewController.FirstController, object: nil)
}
```

The `ViewController` does all the work for transitions.  (Note that getting constraints right still takes some effort.  Start by reducing compression resistance in `SecondContained`'s view.)

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    static let FirstController = "FirstController"
    static let SecondController = "SecondController"

    @IBOutlet weak var container: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "firstSelected:", name: ViewController.FirstController, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "secondSelected:", name: ViewController.SecondController, object: nil)

        // This puts the "SecondContained" controller at location zero in the childViewControllers array.
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("second_contained") as? SecondContained
        if let second = controller {
            addChildViewController(second)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func removePreviousView() {
        if let oldView: NSView = container.subviews[0] {
            oldView.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            print("No previous view found")
        }
    }

    // This is a hack.
    // It would be better to search for the controller by a reliable identifier rather than a number.
    func useController(offset: Int) {
        guard childViewControllers.count > offset else {
            print("Bad offset \(offset) for \(childViewControllers.count)-long array")
            return
        }
        if let controller: NSViewController = childViewControllers[offset] {
            container.addSubview(controller.view)
        } else {
            print("No view controller!?")
        }
    }

    func firstSelected(notification: NSNotification) {
        removePreviousView()
        useController(1)
    }

    func secondSelected(notification: NSNotification) {
        removePreviousView()
        useController(0)
    }

}
```

Note that this is Swift 2.1.  The logic should be portable but I don't know whether some syntax has changed.